# Regression for foreign aid effectiveness

Tags: regression, econometrics, excel

I'm trying to use a multiple regression (in Excel) to determine the effectiveness of foreign aid on GDP growth.  I've forgotten everything since college...

My plan is to run a regression using established determinants as a 'baseline'.  Then run another adding in my independent variable of 'aid expenditures', looking at p-value and coefficient of 'aid expenditures'.  Am I anywhere close?

Comment: As far as I can see it, you just could run a regression including "aid expenditure" as independent variable and look at the coefficient and its confidence interval, $p$-value to assess significance.

Comment: You seem to want economists' advice rather than that of statistical people, although there are people qualified in both on this forum. MS Excel really is a lousy vehicle even for most elementary statistics. My understanding is that it will give you the numeric output you want but not e.g. graphical diagnostics (unless there is some add-on or you write code yourself). Any other statistical package or language would be better. "Multiple regression" is the most common term and I edited accordingly.

Comment: You should also look into newer literature on causal inference

Comment: @COOL The p-value you refer to should not be the p-value of the coefficient (it's practically uninterpretable by itself): you must mean the p-value for the F test of the added variable.

Comment: yes. hierarchical multiple regression is what you're after. if you add predictors one at a time, the R2 change will show you the impact of adding it to your model.